# Is there a keyboard shortcut to hide/show Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, shortcuts, osx-mavericks

I need to instantly access chrome or get it out of my way whenever I need to by using only a fast keyboard shortcut, is there a shortcut for this?

If not, how can I do this?

Comment: This would probably be more of an OS-level hotkey (like Windows' Alt-Tab for example).  Which OS are you using?

Comment: OS X Mavericks.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to instantly access chrome or get it out of my way whenever I need to by using only a fast keyboard shortcut

The simplest solution would be to use a third-party [boss-key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boss_key) [program](http://www.google.com/search?q=boss+key+program+freeware) that can be configured to hide any specified programs.

Amusingly enough, even though a boss-key program’s purpose is to quickly hide the specified program (usually things like games or P2P which people don’t want to get caught using), because it assigns a hotkey to hide and show the specified program, it actually ends up accomplishing what you want, albeit almost as a side-effect.

Comment: As an example, working in another software such as Photoshop or when reading an ebook, sometimes. I need to quickly access chrome to search for something quickly then get back to what I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is quick enough for me, it's not exactly high-tech but hope it helps for you.

*Hide Chrome:*
The 'Hide' command (Apple-H) instantly hides any App in the Dock

*Show Chrome:*
Spotlight (Apple-Space), 'chro', [Enter] pops the App back up in front of whatever else is going on, Apple-T opens a new tab, and highlights the search bar so you can immediately ask Google your question

I don't believe I've got any special settings configured to allow this, but let me know if you get different behaviour and I'll try and work out the differences. (OSX Mavericks 10.9.1, Chrome 31.0.1650.63)